# Why is beautifulsoup4 not importing to my script?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, module

Before I explain my problem I want to start by saying that I have looked all over this site for an answer and tried almost all of them, to no avail.

I am on a windows machine, in a virtual environment. I have a command prompt opened in the virtual environment. I have already pip installed over a dozen modules that are being imported into my script and working perfectly. When I run the line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I get this error:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

In my command prompt I can do 'pip list' and see beautifulsoup4 version 4.9.0.  As well as in my virtual environment folder I can go into Lib\site-packages and I see all of my other installed packages that work in my script, along with a folder called 'bs4' and one called 'beautifulsoup4-4.9.0.dist-info'.  I have also tried pip uninstall beautifulsoup4 and then re installed it, confirming that it did not show up in pip list between running those.

I am completely at a loss for why I cannot access the bs4 module. Anyone have any ideas for me to try?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I am currently using VS Code and have pip installed several other modules including pymysql and google-api packages. I have successfully connected to my gmail and Amazon RDS database, so i know the other modules are working properly. For some reason its only BeautifulSoup4 I am having issues with.

EDIT 2:  I opened up ipython from my virtual environment, and I entered from bs4 import beautifulsoup and i get this error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\Projects\VirtualENVs\test_venv\Lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)
```

EDIT 3: I finally just opened a new command prompt and pip installed beautifulsoup4 onto my computer outside of the virtual environment and now it works fine.

Comment: Are you running your code with correct interpreter?

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL I am using VS CODE and it shows my interpreter is C:\Python38\python.exe    I am curious how my other modules would be working if the interpreter was set incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe other modules also installed in the current interpreter? You should change your interpreter to virtualenv one.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL When i go to change my interpreter, there are only 2 options. I tried typing in the path to the python.exe in my venv, but it wont accept that. When I select the other interpreter I get errors about my other modules that have been working. I am not sure if i am doing it correctly.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL I added a 2nd edit in my main comment. It looks like even when i launch a new python instance in the virtual environment, its still giving me an error. I would assume there is soemthing wrong with the bs4 package, but i could be wrong. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know, I up voted your quetion. Hopefuly someone will help.